# ROUND IF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want a function that will round a number differentially depending on the value in another cell. If my values are, for examples, 0.25 97 2.75 I want the middle number to donate 0.25 to each cell to round them up to the nearest 0.5 so they are 0.5 96.5 3.0. But if the numbers are 0.5 98 1.5 they can stay as they are but I would want 0.75 96.25 3.0 I would want it to become 1.0 96.0 3.0. I've tried ROUND IF but I can't get it quite right.

I've tried FLOOR, CEILING and ROUND IF but I just get get it to do exactly what I want.

```
=FLOOR(D26,0.5)

=ROUNDDOWN(D26,0.5)IF(C26, E26,.25,.75)

=ROUNDUP(C26,0.5)*IF(D98,0.25,0.75)
```

Comment: What you want is definitely not FLOOR, CEILING or ROUND. It might help if you explain WHY you want to achieve that, or WHAT you want to achieve. To give you a useful answer, we need to understand the math behind those decisions.

Comment: You can't do it with just the three cells and formulas, because as soon as you change the first cell, the logic that changed it would no longer apply so it would change back, ad infinitum. So either you need two hidden columns holding the original values or a VBA formula

Comment: So i’m calculating probe efficiencies and I want to err on the side of caution. The three figures are a combined score from two analysts. If the right or left hand numbers end in .25 or .75 I want to round the right and left hand numbers up to the nearest .5 and take away from the middle number to do this. So far so good? Thanks for your help

Comment: is it ok for the middle number to be x.25 or x.75? - this would happen if only one of the other numbers is x.25 or x.75

Comment: No. If the middle number had a .25 or a .75 then it would be rounded down and the corresponding .25/.75 to the right or left would be rounded up.

Comment: If your problem has been solved (as per your comment) you must consider to mark the question as answered. Tick the checkmark next to either answer that you feel has been most helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea for you:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=CEILING.MATH(A2,0.5)
```

Formula in `E2`:

```
=FLOOR.MATH(SUM(A2:C2)-(D2+F2),0.5)
```

Formula in `F2`:

```
=CEILING.MATH(C2,0.5)
```

---

*Edited `E2` formula to take into consideration the rounding when the middle number would be stuck on either `.25` or `.75`*

Comment: Neat, my attempt would have been twice as long.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 3 numbers are in D4, D5 and D6, then the following formulas can be applied in say E4 - E6:

```
=ROUND(D4*2,0)/2
=D5-(E4-D4)-(E6-D6)
=ROUND(D6*2,0)/2
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you all, you’ve been massively helpful :-)